# how to make passive Jframe in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

hi i am using jframe,

i have a main() class on login page, when people logon than i use

```
adminForm = new AdminForm();                    
adminForm.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
```

now i can set visible my adminForm, i have an edit and add button on the adminForm, when people push the add button, i want to open new frame

```
yAdmin = new Add();
yAdmin.setVisible(true);
```

now i want people just edit yAdmin, people can see the adminForm but they cant touch it before the yAdmin closed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `JFrame` use a `JDialog` for `yAdmin`, make it modal with `adminForm` as its owner:

```
 yAdmin = new JDialog(adminForm,true);
```

or let `Add` extend JDialog accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
frame.setAlwaysOnTop (true);
```

or you can use modal dialogue:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog ();
dialog.setModal (true);
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop (true);
dialog.setModalityType (ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

Comment: frame.setAlwaysOnTop(rue); this is setting my frame on top but i can click adminForm still, i want adminForm must be passive when yAdmin is open.

Comment: Change yAdmin.SetEnabled(false); when other form is on top.

Comment: yes i set yAdmin.SetEnabled(false) now its passive but when people push X they cant close the y.Admin cuz i cant control X, anyway i try your advice JDialog, i create a Jdialog and i call it in my form, but my constructor is public admin_add(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    } but i cant call this yAdmin = new admin_add(adminForm,true);

Comment: i called yAdmin = new admin_add(this,true); i dont understand why i cant call my Form name, ty for help,